# Printing out box drawing characters (extended-ascii) in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I want to print box-drawing character in Output messages in SSMS. It includes characters like e.g. ║ or  ░ or ╬.
The full list of characters which I have in my mind can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character).

When I am trying the following: `PRINT '╬'` it returns simply `+` while I am expecting `╬`.

When I am executing `SELECT ASCII('╬')` it returns `43`, but when I am executing `SELECT CHAR(43)` it returns (not surprisingly) `+`.

Is it related to collation? If so, how can I find which collation to use?

Comment: Maybe try `N'╬'`, `unicode(N'╬')` and `nchar(<probably another number than 43>)`.

Comment: Tip: Windows generally includes a `character map` application that will display all of the characters (with name, Unicode code point, ...) in a font. You can use it to copy character(s) that you can paste into your queries. Depending on what you're doing it may be clearer to create _faux_ constants, e.g. `declare @Box_Top_Left_Corner as NChar(1) = NChar( 0x250C );`, that you can use elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple literal in SQL-Server is - by default a `CHAR / VARCHAR` type. This type is *1-byte-encoded extended ASCII*: The lower half is the *plain latin* character set, the upper half is depending on a collation. This means, there is very little support for non-standard characters.

The second character type is `NCHAR / NVARCHAR`. This is (almost) unicode, very close to `utf-16`. The actual encoding is *two-byte encoded `UCS-2`*. The support for non-standard characters is (almost) complete. Any literal starting with a `N` is treated as `NCHAR / NVARCHAR`:

Try this:

```
SELECT '╬',N'╬';

DECLARE @str1a VARCHAR(10)='╬';
DECLARE @str1b VARCHAR(10)=N'╬'; --The NVARCHAR literal is changed to VARCHAR
DECLARE @str2 NVARCHAR(10)=N'╬'; 

SELECT @str1a,@str1b,@str2;
```

The functions to get the *code point* and - vice versa - to get the character are two-folded too:

```
SELECT ASCII('a'), UNICODE(N'a')
      ,ASCII('╬'), UNICODE(N'╬')
      ,CHAR(97),NCHAR(97),CHAR(43),NCHAR(43)
      ,NCHAR(9580)--does not work with `CHAR`
```

Comment: `NCHAR()` - this is exactly what I needed and what finally answers my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to print then in Unicode, i.e. to prefix them with `N`:

```
PRINT N'╬'
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question indeed however I would like also to do it this way: `PRINT CHAR(XXX)`. Is it possible? should I use some specific collation then? How to find out which one?

Comment: @PawełPilch what do you mean by your print comment? The CHAR function is for ASCII characters and the character here is NOT part of the ascii set, hence why you have to use unicode. But it isn't clear what you want there. Do you want the code for your character? If so, use the UNICODE function.